# .htaccess 500 error. RewriteRule not working as it should

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with one of my .htaccess rewriterule:
Server details:
Server runs LiteSpeed Webserver not Apache, according to my host provider it's 100% compatible with apache mod_rewrite.
Problem:
I get 500 Internal Server Error when i use this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  Options +Indexes  
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).mysite.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$  %2/$1 [L,QSA,NC]
</IfModule>
```

When I use this code, it pretty much does what it is suppose to do it redirects traffic from any sub-domain to a corresponding sub-folder with file request also. No Error, no nothing it works OK but it also changes the browser's address which i don't wish.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  Options +Indexes  
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).mysite.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://mysite.com/%2/$1 [L,QSA,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas?

Editetd : One thing i would like to mention is that i use wildcard DNS the subdomain don't realy exist. 
Editted yet again :    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %2/index.php [L,QSA,NC] if i use this rule and try to acces a http://sub.mysite.com/whatever it succesfuly redirects it to http://mysite.com/sub/index.php i don't get it why it does not work with $1 instead of index.php when i change them i get 500 internal server error.

Got the solution now :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA] [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}     !^www\.mysite\.com$              [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}     ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %2==$1           !^(.*)==\1                                        
RewriteRule ^(.*) %2/$1$2$3   [L,QSA,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: for 500 error check error logs of the server - they will tell you everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting generic problem which merits a generic solution, so how about:

```
#
# Rule matches ('fred','','')    for pattern 'fred'
#              ('123','/',fred') for pattern '123/fred'
# At cond 2 %2 is the subdomain e.g. 123 for www.123.mysite.com
# Hence cond 3 pattern is 123==123 for www.123.mysite.com/123/fred
# and this will match ^(.*?)==\1 or fail its negation
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}     !^www\.mysite\.com$              [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}     ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %2==$1           !^(.*?)==\1                                        
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(/?)(.*) %1/$1$2$3                        [L]
```

Comment: It's working fine now the redirect but now i have a stupid thing happening :)

Comment: When i try to access the index.php in the test subdomain it redirects to domain.com/test/index.php which is what i wish. The problem is that for testing i used a index.php similar to the one in the domain.com only that i did not place the image pictures and style.css of the domain.com index in the test subfolder but when i acces test.domain.com for the first time it uses the style.css from domain.com and when i press refresh i does not use it any more it just display the text whitout the css which is normal. Can you tell me why the first time it used the style from domain.com?

Comment: i manage to resolve this problem by rewriting all traffic with www. which works fine now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is because it is creating an infinite rewrite loop.
`123.mysite.com/` get rewritten to `123.mysite.com/123/`, which gets rewritten to `123.mysite.com/123/123/` etc.

Try using this to prevent this loop:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  %2/$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: i just don't think it is this case, it works if i use the code with http://mysite.com/%2/$1 in fact it works perfectly but as i posted in my question it redirects the webbrowser to http://mysite.com/subdomain_folder/whatever... and i wish to just point to mysite.com/subdomain_folder/whatever and in the webbrowser the adressbar should indicate http://subdomain.mysite.com/whatever... In fact i think the problem is how the server interprets the $1 variable

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong code from your question. I edited it and it should work now.

Comment: Don't you want to bump the REDIRECT_STATUS condition up one so that %2 is set from the *last* `RewriteCond` and so correctly for the rewrite rule?

Comment: Stupid me. Thanks for spotting that @TerryE. Edited again. Sorry George.

Comment: I'm stumped. I just tested it on my own server, just to be sure, and it worked like it should. No 500. Try retyping the code into a fresh new file, to make sure there are no hidden characters in your text. Otherwise I can't help you I'm afraid.

Comment: @Gerben i just can't get it to work is either the server acting stupid or i am stupid. I modified the script as you sayed and yet got the same 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

I think your rule should be re-written like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mysite.com/%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```

P flag will make it act like a proxy and will keep the URL in browser to `subdomain.mysite.com/whatever` instead of `mysite.com/subdomain/whatever`

Comment: Anubhava, I am intrigued by your use of the [proxy] flag.  Surely this relies on mod_proxy being loaded and also needs to be supported by the appropriate `ProxyPassReverse` directives.  Most hosting providers and LAMP stack disable mod_proxy because of the possible exploitation issues.

Comment: @TerryE: OP wants a redirection where domain-name is changing but OP still doesn't want an external redirect and doesn't want to change browser's URL. IMO 'P' is the only way to make it possible as 'R' will certainly change the URL in browser. However I'm not sure if 'P' is available to OP or not.

Comment: not working but thanks anyway and by the way i use wildcard dns for subdomains and the .htaccess file we are talking about here is in the root of the main domain.

Comment: `not working` is never a helpful error for somebody trying to answer your problem :) Are you getting 500 internal error? OR are you getting looping? Pls provide me matching lines from error.log or access.log from Apache.

Comment: Anubhava, yes the O/P doesn't want to R=30x but otherwise this is just standard internal redirection using the HTTP_HOST subdomain -- a standard trick on many shared services including the one that I use.  No mod_proxy needed.

Comment: @TerryE: If I understood OP correctly he's asking redirection of `sub.mysite.com/whatever` to `mysite.com/sub/whatever` and since it is changing domain name as well, can this be an internal redirection?

Comment: @George87: Can you pls try taking out 'P' flag from my code and then test.

Comment: @anubhava removed it and the redirect works but it changes the browser url too

Comment: That is what I was discussing with @TerryE here. P flag was there to provide this feature however it requires that mod_proxy needs to be enabled.