# .htaccess - RewriteRule from subfolder to root without redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, root

I'm looking for something in `.htaccess` to change 
`subdomain.website.com/page/title`
to
`website.com/subdomain/title`

without redirecting to the website and while keeping the URL in the address bar.

This `.htaccess` gets called in a subfolder. `ublic_html/subdomain`. So how do I get back to that folder `public_html` without using a redirect.

Thanks :)

Comment: I see now I wasn't very clear. In the RewriteRule I use /index.php?blabla but when I use it here it's acyually subdomain/index?blabla. So is it possible to use the upper folder/root

Comment: No, unless you place it (the rule) in parent .htaccess (in your case -- file in root folder). But if you want -- you can try `[DPI]` and/or `[PT]` flag (have not tested this myself).

Comment: You are expected to search the the `.htaccess` tagged Qs for a solution *before* posting your Q.  This one has been asked and answered dozens of times :(

Comment: Sorry, couldn't find the one that with a specific enough solution for my problem, but I believe I have it working now

Answer (score -1):

Here is one way to do it using a proxy, which will leave the URL in the users address bar unchanged.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.website\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^page/title$ http://website.com/subdomain/title [P,NC]
```

Comment: Ulrich, you are wrong.  You *really* don't need to use a proxy to do this -- many if not most shared hosting providers map `.*\.mydomian.com` to a single DOCUMENT_ROOT for `mydomain.com`.  All the OP is asking for is an internal redirection on the subdomain. I've just given the rule for this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023448/htaccess-500-error-rewriterule-not-working-as-it-should/9025887#9025887) on another post.